# Using FBX Exporter messes up materials of VRM?

Tags: unity, blender, materials, fbx

I am trying to export a VRM into an FBX to edit in Blender.
To do this, I have installed UniVRM to import the VRM, and FBXExporter to export it as an FBX.

This almost works great. However, I have an issue where the resulting FBX has messed up materials. Please see below comparisons of how the materials of `PlainGuy7` appear in the Unity editor, versus how they appear in Blender (`Material preview` selected).

What might be the cause for this? In Unity I am able to assign it the old material and that works fine but my future workflow plans are definitely disrupted by this problem.

[image: Unity]

[image: Blender]

Comment: So you are importing the VRM into Unity and then from Unity into Blender? I got much better results by importing the VRM into Blender directly using [this Blender add-on](https://github.com/saturday06/VRM_Addon_for_Blender) and then getting the model from Blender to Unity as FBX.

Comment: That is the answer for me; thank you.